# Catching errors with DBD::Informix

Tags: perl, informix, dbi

I need to run dynamically constructed queries against Informix IDS 9.x; while WHERE clause is mostly quite simple, Projection clause can be quite complicated with lots of columns and formulas applied to columns. Here is one example:

```
SELECT ((((table.I_ACDTIME + table.I_ACWTIME + table.I_DA_ACDTIME + table.I_DA_ACWTIME +
           table.I_RINGTIME))+(table.I_ACDOTHERTIME + table.I_ACDAUXINTIME + 
           table.I_ACDAUX_OUTTIME)+(table.I_TAUXTIME + table.I_TAVAILTIME + 
           table.I_TOTHERTIME)+((table.I_AVAILTIME + table.I_AUXTIME)*
         ((table.MAX_TOT_PERCENTS/100)/table.MAXSTAFFED)))/(table.INTRVL*60))
FROM table
WHERE ...
```

The problem arises when some of the fields used contain zeroes; Informix predictably throws division by zero error, but the error message is not very helpful:

```
DBD::Informix::st fetchrow_arrayref failed:
SQL: -1202: An attempt was made to divide by zero.
```

In this case, it is desirable to return NULL upon failed calculation. Is there any way to achieve this other than parse Projection clause and enclose each and every division attempt in CASE ... END? I would prefer to use some DBD::Informix magic if it's there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you'll be able to solve this with DBD::Informix or any other database client, without resorting to parsing the SQL and rewriting it. There's no option to just ignore the column with the /0 arithmetic: the whole statement fails when the error is encountered, at the engine level.

If it's any help, you can write the code to avoid /0 as a `DECODE` rather than `CASE ... END`, which is a little cleaner, ie:

```
DECODE(table.MAXSTAFFED, 0, NULL,
  ((table.MAX_TOT_PERCENTS/100)/table.MAXSTAFFED)))/(table.INTRVL*60)))
```

Comment: I do think the same but had to check before going this way. Thanks for DECODE() tip, I'm not too familiar with Informix and didn't know about this function.

Comment: If Informix supports `NULLIF`, then this becomes NULLIF(..., 0) which could be considered even neater.

Answer (score 1):

DBD::Informix is an interface to the Informix DBMS, and as thin as possible (which isn't anywhere near as thin as I'd like, but that's another discussion).  Such behaviour cannot reasonably be mediated by DBD::Informix (or any other DBD driver accessing a DBMS); it must be handled by the DBMS itself.

IDS does not provide a mechanism to yield NULL in lieu of a divide by zero error.  It might be a reasonable feature request - but it would not be implemented until the successor version to Informix 11.70 at the earliest.

Note that Informix Dynamic Server (IDS) 9.x is several years beyond the end of its supported life (10.00 is also unsupported).

Comment: OK so if DBD::Informix author says no magic, then there's none. Thanks. As for the version, I know it's badly outdated but upgrade is out of question in this case. Besides, it works really well most of the time so there would be little incentive to upgrade even if it was possible. :)

Answer (score 0):

From experience working with informix I would say you woud be lucky to get that kind of functionallity within IDS (earlier versions of IDS - not much earlier than your version - had barely any string manipulation function nevermind anything complicated.)

I would save yourself the time and generate the calculations against an in memory list.

Comment: It is not the case; I take predefined queries from report templates which I cannot change. The only thing I can do is parse and replace but I don't like it, too unreliable.